# Trying to implement mutex and synchronization in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex, synchronous

First of all, I think that all my problems could be more or less solved if I made my method which incurs in a race condition of the type synchronized. I cant use it, because I want to be "manually" able to check if there is a Thread currently using the method, put it to wait until the previous thread finishes and then manually awaken it/notify so the new thread can execute the method.
I am new to Threading in general and Java threading in particular. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

```
**Problem**:

I am trying to start a bunch of threads of the same class.
Below you can see its run method.

     @Override
        public void run() {
    
             if (!lck.tryLock()) { //sort of mutex
                    System.out.println(this.toString() + "waiting");
                try {
                    synchronize();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
                
            }
    
            methodRaceCondition(this);
            condition=true; //variable i am tryng to use to make the method below "awaken" the waiting threads.
            lck.unlock();
            
        }
```

I created a Lock (ReentrantLock) so I can check if there is a thread currently using the method with critical section -so i avoid race condition.
If there is one thread using this methodRaceCondition, I want to make the newcomer thread wait. I used a new method for it, bc as far as I know you can just make a thread wait and notify inside a synchronized method (and, I cant/dont want to use it, see above), so I created this synchronized method.

```
public synchronized void synchronize() throws InterruptedException {
        while(!condition) {
            wait();
        }
        
        notifyAll(); // 
    }
```

Here, what I (unseccesfully try to) do is make a thread wait (in case a thread N helds the lock), once the thread N is done, in the run method i want to make the while condition true, so that all the threads waiting are notifie/awaken.

However, if I run it, a deadlock happens. I am just not able to awaken all the waiting threads! and the program cant finish.

I cant figure out how to solve this. I hope I am being clear enough.

****UPLOAD****
My solution, so far, using semaphores, as a poster suggested. I was stuck in this idea of using locks and monitors, etc. Semaphores look enough. It does the job, Suggestions very welcome.

```
@Override
    public void run() {

        //synchronization, if busy, show that the method is occupied and wait.
        if (!semaphoreSinc.tryAcquire()) {
            System.out.println(this.toString() + "waiting");
            try {
                semaphoreSinc.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Socio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
        
        //mutex to prevent race condition
        try {
            mutex.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Socio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        methodRaceCondition(this);
        //done, let other possible threads access it
                mutex.release();
        //awaken waiting threads
        semaphoreSinc.release();


    }
```

****QUESTION:****
Would it be possible to replicate this behaviour with monitors?

Comment: You should post some more of your code. What is the definition of `condition`?

Comment: Manually using `wait()` and `notify()` is _certainly_ more low-level than is appropriate for this problem. Why would you not just use `lck.lock()` here?  Why are you trying to manually manage awakening?

Comment: Right, instead of language primitives like `wait()` and `notify()`, you should first look at the classes in `java.util.concurrent`.  The `Semaphore` class in that package seems to do what you want.  So why aren't you using it?

Comment: @markspace Hello. I was not using them bc I was not framing the problem correctly. Your suggestion has been very helpful. I've been able to make it work

Comment: @LouisWasserman I was manually trying to manage awakening because I thought that this was the way I had to achieve what I ve done in the uploaded new code (with semaphores). I think the code will be clearer than what I can try to explain with verbose.